# Distributed & Cloud GIS Resources

Tags: references, cloud-gis

Are there any definitive research papers, web resources, or (text)books on distributed GIS? Topics I'm interested in are:

- Parallelism of sequential spatial algorithms
- Frameworks for implementing GIS in either the cloud/cluster environment
- FOSS and commercial software for the above

I have seen [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/is-there-an-architecture-for-distributed-geoprocessing) question, but I want something a bit more definitive. CW status would be beneficial, as well as recommendations for tags.

EDIT: I have entered a number of these terms on [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com), and while I am a graduate student and deal with research papers on a regular basis many of the results are not substantive or encompassing.

Comment: You are going to find not a lot of solid information here. The majority of the work in this area is adhoc or highly custom work for governmental clients who need mega-processing. At my agency we have taken ESRI code and made it scale more for our needs but it requires a great deal of care.

Comment: I implicitly assumed that, as much of my searching has not yielded a solid, vetted resource. I am actively involved in researching some of these items, and so far I have had to meld my academic training with these concepts with little guidance. I am also involved in some consulting with a super-computing center, and they are interested in developing scalable GIS solutions. See my edit above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have done several projects in this regard, but at the end they always ended up being custom solutions that basically

- separated the problem in grids
- did the processing in each individual node and copied the result to a temp table / data store
- merged all the solutions to a single result table and optionally handled boundary conditions. Handling boundary conditions was only required for cases where features needed to be stitched or massaged (for example when building a topology in a distributed manner, you want the boundary features to snap).

Funny enough, every single time I solved a problem of this nature, I used a different technology, mostly because that was the fad of the time. At the end, what you want is a message passing library that has a job queue manager, spawns processes on the different nodes, and that has some sort of synchronization mechanism ([Semapahore's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29), [Barrier's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_%28computer_science%29), etc) and some way to handle errors and retry. All the projects I mention below have these things.

For geo, I have used (in chronological order):

(old school)

- [CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture)
- [DCOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model)
- an [MPI](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/index.html) implementation known as [MPICH](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/)

(newer)

- [Gearman](http://gearman.org/)
- [Apache Hadoop MapReduce](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/)
- [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/)

There are **several** others that people use.

At the end, any of these would cut it (albeit in a slightly different way), so it boils down to picking one that has a community that is helpful.

Also, on every node, you would have to use a library to do the GIS geometry operations. The recommendation for which one to use would come based on the language that you prefer to code this in. But I am sure the options that most people would give you would be:

- [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/)
- [JTS](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm)
- [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/)
- [ArcObject's Geometry module](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ESRI_ArcGIS_Geometry/002m0000004s000000/)

Or some other library that serves as wrappers to one of these.

Comment: Nice! Currently I am learning Apache Hadoop MapReduce and CGAL, that's really what I had planned on attempting first. I had been holding onto this because I didn't want to flood my question with resources I already in my possession, but I found this useful: http://www.nathankerr.com/projects/parallel-gis-processing/alternative_approaches_to_parallel_gis_processing.html

Comment: MapReduce and CGAL are excellent selections. Can't go wrong with them.

Answer (score 1):

We are developing a MapReduce based system with SQL interface for large scale spatial data management.

More details can be found @ http://confluence.cci.emory.edu:8090/confluence/display/HadoopGIS/Home
http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2213603